# How to get all the Child of the firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[with provinceCode database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjCcx.png)

[This is the database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlhtT.png)

[this is the json file from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjHqm.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjHqm.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RTFj.png this is the file

> dreference =
>   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("provinsi").child("0")

if I do like this just got one list only

Source code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var dreference : DatabaseReference
    private var datalist: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    private var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
    private var listener : ValueEventListener?= null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val prov = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.provinsi)
        val listProv: MutableList<String> = ArrayList() // menampung nama provinsi
        adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
        //SETUP DB
        dreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("provinsi")
        dreference?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
            override fun onDataChange(task: DataSnapshot) {
                if(task.exists()){
                    val provname=task.child("provinceName").value.toString()
                    listProv.add(provname)
                    initSpinner(prov,listProv)
                }
            }

        })


    }

    fun initSpinner(obj : Spinner, arr : MutableList<String>){
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                arr
        )
        obj.adapter = adapter
    }

}
```

I want to get all the province name from Provinsi array
Thanks

Comment: add ur database

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry i forgot to attach it

Comment: @PeterHaddad i have added in link

Comment: To be more clear, you want to get the value of `provinceName` and what's inside `provinceCode`, right? In that case, please show us what's inside `provinceCode` by adding a new screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo i already add it

Comment: What you have added now is totally different than what you have added in the first place. What the actual structure that you are using?

Comment: @AlexMamo i make the file in json. i import the json to firebase and the structure suddenly become like that with 0 extend, 1 extend, 2 extend

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand you.

Comment: @AlexMamo its ok i already get the answer
Thanks